# Hat Matching Experiment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In the hat matching problem (without replacement) we have to write a probability mass function for the random variable $A_i$ which is the indicator random variable for the event that a match happens at $i^{\text{th}}$ slot.

Here's my attempt: Since the sample space is $n!$ we choose $i$ from $n$ i.e. $\binom{n}{i}$, for remaining slots, we have $(n-1)!$ and probability of getting correct hat (for $A_1$ is $1/n$)
So, would $A_1$ be $\displaystyle \frac{n \cdot (n-1)!}{n!} \cdot \frac{1}{n}$? If not, what can $A_1$ be?

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{n \cdot (n-1)!}{n!}$ is just 1, isn't it?

Comment: Right  I didn't see that.

Comment: What could be A1 though?